# ggplot2: force legend to have one row when guides does not appear to have an effect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following toy example:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
mpg$drv <- sample(as.character((-4:4)), size = length(mpg$drv), replace = T)
g + geom_bar(aes(fill = drv), position = "fill") + theme(legend.position = "bottom") + guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

which for me[image] yields the following figure.

Try as I might, I am unable to get the legend at the bottom to be in one row. I looked around and the `guide_legend` appears to be having no effect. Is there a better way to do this, or is there another way to force the legend to be in one row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've specified `colour` instead of `fill` in `guides`. Try this instead:

```
library(ggplot2)
mpg$drv <- sample(as.character((-4:4)), size = length(mpg$drv), replace = T)
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill = drv), position = "fill") + theme(legend.position = "bottom") + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much. I guess I did not realize that changing the fill was an option because the help page does not mention it at all. Thanks again! I will mark the answer in 5 minutes when I am allowed to.

Comment: I must agree with you that the ggplot documentation available as part of its help pages leaves quite a bit to be desired. Hence the need to search SO.